# PhpStorm how to author name change on git push

Tags: phpstorm

During the command git push with PhpStorm uses the old user name (Alex). How to change it to another?
Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO1kV.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you permanently want to change it, just alter your Git config. Open up a terminal window (either from within PhpStorm or from your OS) and run:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Of course, use the appropriate username/email address. If you just want to push a single commit with another author name, you can set it in the commit dialog on the top right, use `username <email>` syntax when you use that.

Comment: Needed to change my name and this did it! Thanks @Oldskool